# Why doesn't this command line (Batch file) work?

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

I have a command line which looks for certain IDs (2 IDs )in 2nd column. But I want this command to search all the columns, not just second column.
Can anyone help?
The command line for searching 2nd column is:

```
findstr /rb /c:"[^|]*| *ID1 *|" /c:"[^|]*| *ID2 *|" "src.txt" >" dest.txt"
```

Can someone modify it so that it searches all the columns instead of just the second and also give 2 command lines which will:

(1) Searches all the columns instead of just 2nd.

(2) Searches only for 1 ID.

(3) Searches only for 3 IDs.

src.txt -
The text is in this manner:

Ja | 11 | xxx

Jn | 19 | yyy

Jx | 21 | yyyas | sas

Also few lines may have more columns like that last one.

Thanks!

Comment: If you show the text you are searching and outline what you need to find then your question may be clearer.

Comment: Show some examples of what you are searching for also.

Comment: I am searching for strings which start with J (see column 1). But in few lines, strings with J can be in column 2 or 3. 
So I want a command which searches for strings which start with J in all the columns.

Give me 3 different command lines which perform the tasks mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find in `src.txt` containing the lines

```
Ja | 11 | xxx
Jn | 19 | yyy
nJ | 19 | yyy
Ax | 21 | Jyyas | sas
Ax | 23 | yyJas | sas
```

only the 3 lines where a value within a column starts with `J` and therefore writting to file `dest.txt` the lines

```
Ja | 11 | xxx
Jn | 19 | yyy
Ax | 21 | Jyyas | sas
```

the following command can be used

```
findstr /R /C:"^J" /C:"\| *J" "src.txt" >"dest.txt"
```

`^J` is for finding lines starting with `J` and `\| *J` is for finding lines having a value starting with `J` after 0 or more spaces in a different column than first column.

Please note that parameter `/B` is removed as otherwise this would not work.
`/rb` in your example is `/R` an `/B` combined in one parameter string.

Comment: What if there were no " | " and they were plain sentences like -

Ja 11 xxx

Comment: More over there are many columns and rows and they might have strings starting with other alphabets. I want only ones with "J" filtered from those rows and columns and printed to another text file.

Comment: Alright, I got it. Is there any way to ignore certain text while using findstr?

Let's say there's a line with "Jx | what | why | 15" which will be copied to another txt because of that findstr command above, but can findstr filter out what and why and print only "jx | 15"?